# ASP.NET 4.0 DataList problem - Facebook Like Button doesn't show up

Tags: asp.net, facebook, button, facebook-like, datalist

I have a problem with placing Facebook Like Button inside a DataList control. I want to dynamicly create a Like Button for every DataList element. The problem is that it does show up only in IE. It doesn't work in other browsers.

Here is the code placed inside DataList control:

```
<fb:like href="<%#"http://www.mojsekret.net/Komentarze.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ID")%>" send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="true" font="">
<br>
</fb:like>
```

And here is the script attachment:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/pl_PL/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
```

So it is basic stuff generated from facebook dev site. Has anyone encountered similar problem? Please guys, help me.

BTW: I did the same thing with Google +1 button and it's working. Code:

```
<g:plusone href='<%#"http://www.mojsekret.net/Komentarze.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ID")%>'></g:plusone>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `<br>` inside the fb:like tag. Also make sure you are only rendering one `<div id="fb-root">` on your whole page.